# Atmosphere jQuery responseBody always starts with length pipe "5|"

Tags: javascript, jquery, atmosphere, atmosphere.js

I'm trying to work with the atmosphere-framework.
Sending and receiving data works pretty well but i think there is some incompatibility or other problem when jquery reads the received message:

When the server sends back "Text" like in the code of my TestService.java the jQuery-client receives a responseBody "4|Text" (=> length of the text|text). Of course i could just cut out the number and the pipe but i'm trying to figure out what's the problem in the first place.

So when i load the html-page at first i get an alert saying just "|". Then, everytime i click the send-button i get an alert "4|Text". Sometimes after a timeout of 2 minutes i even get an alert "1|X".

```
atmosphere-runtime version is: 2.2.7
jQuery-Version is: 2.1.4
jquery.atmosphere-version is: 2.2.7-jquery from https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-javascript
```

I also tried other combinations of versions but it never fixed the problem.

I got the same problem on Glassfish, but at the moment i am using WildFly 8.1. The problem is the same for Opera, Firefox and Chromium.

My TestService class looks like this, i think it is working correctly:

```
@ManagedService(path="/")
public class TestService {

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestService.class);

@Ready
public void onReady(AtmosphereResource r) {
    logger.info("Resource {} connected", r.uuid());
}

@Message(decoders = {JacksonDecoder.class})
public String onMessage(AtmosphereResource r, Test t) throws IOException {
    logger.info("Message received = " + t.toString());
    return "Text";
}   
}
```

The code for sending and receiving on the jQuery-client looks like this:

```
var socket = $.atmosphere;
var usersUpdateReq = {
    url: '/NewQuiz-web/quiz',
    transport: 'websocket',
    fallbackTransport: 'long-polling',
    contentType: "application/javascript"
};
usersUpdateReq.onMessage = function(resp) {
    if(resp.status === 200) {
    alert("received: >>" + resp.responseBody + "<<");
    console.log(resp.responseBody);
    eval(resp.responseBody);
    }
};
usersUpdateReq.onError = function(resp) {
    alert('Error');
    console.log(resp);
};

var usersUpdateSubSock = socket.subscribe(usersUpdateReq);
```

Sending an example-request:

```
$("#sendb").click(function() {
    usersUpdateSubSock.push($.stringifyJSON({ name : "TestTest" }));
});
```

Please let me know if you need additional information. Thank you people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both behaviors are expected.

The first one (strings like `4|text`) is to track the length of your response (see more info [here](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/jQuery.atmosphere.js-atmosphere.js-API#trackmessagelength-default--false)). In that way the client will validate that the response content received is complete. But, to have this fully configured, you need to add the following property to your `request` object in the `client` side (in your case `usersUpdateReq`):

```
trackMessageLength : true
```

The second one (strings like `1|X`) represents the heartbeat the keep alive the connection between the server and client. See more info [here](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Keeping-a-connection-active-using-an-Heartbeat-AtmosphereInterceptor). And of course you can configure it in the [server](http://atmosphere.github.io/atmosphere/apidocs/org/atmosphere/cpr/ApplicationConfig.html#HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS) and [client side](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/jQuery.atmosphere.js-atmosphere.js-API#heartbeatserver-defaultnull).

Comment: Thank you for your response! I added the option and now it works as intented! So just for me to understand what the problem was: The trackMessageLength-feature is by default enabled on the server but is deactivated on the client?